# How to call one method in imported componet

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue, I have a one render file. inside that file i have import two component. component-A and component-B. Component-B have all the methods. how can i call component-B method details in Component-A

Comment: Is better to emit from B back to parent and parent calls something in A via a refs, though you could traverse from B with `this.$parent` into A, or obviously use vuex

Comment: Thanks you for your valuable response @LawrenceCherone